# Vue component is not visible

Tags: vue.js, components

My app,js:

```
Vue.component('member-edit', require('./components/MemberEdit.vue'));
Vue.component('billings', require('./components/Billings.vue'));
```

My component member edit wants to use component billings like this in html dom:

```
                <billings></billings>
```

and below in script:

```
    import {Billings} from '../components/Billings.vue'
    components: {
        Billings,
    },
```

My billing component has name like this:

```
 export default {
    name: "billings",
}
```

But still I have error:

```
app.js:14717 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <billings> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Where is my mistake? My component name is : Billings.vue

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `{}` from the import.

The `{}` is used for [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which is unnecessary for your case.

Just use

```
import Billings from '../components/Billings.vue'
```